How to read JSON object with unknown key?
I am trying to read a JSON object containing list of unknown key in my template file (HTML) using Angular v18. But getting error stating:

Type 'JSON' is not assignable to Record<string, string | ((text: string, reviver?: ...)

Interface to capture response (response-data.ts)
export interface ResponseData {
  action: string,
  data: JSON[],
  warn_info: string
}

app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  metaService = inject(MetaService);
  respData = ({} as any) as ResponseData;
  ...

  async fetchMetaDatails(criteria: string) {
    await this.metaService.getDatails(criteria).subscribe({
      next: (resp) => {
        this.respData = resp;
      },
      error: (e) => {
        console.log('Error in fetching metaDetails: ', e);
      }
    });
  } 
}

Structure of Sample Response:
{
   "data": [
      {
         "col1": "val1",
         "col2": "val2",
         ..... // 100s of entries
      },
      {
         "col1": "val1",
         "col2": "val2",
         ..... // 100s of entries
      }
   ]
}

Below is my sample code to read the data in template file (HTML)
@if(respData && respData.data) {
  @for(row of respData.data; track $index) {
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of row | keyvalue ">
      <td>{{obj.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  }
}

This line where I mentioned '<tr *ngFor="let obj of row | keyvalue ">' is giving error stating row is

row: Type 'JSON' is not assignable to Record<string, string | ((text: string, reviver?: ...)

I tried a few other approaches as well, but nothing seems to work.

issue not reproducible stackblitz its let obj of row, please replicate and share in the question if the issue still persists

Pls use Angular v18 to reproduce the issue.

still not reproducible stackblitz please modify it so that the issue happens

Where does the error come from? There is no JSON in your code. Is this a JavaScript or TypeScript error?

Updated the question. Added required details. Let me know if you still need any additional info.

Where is the assignment that causes the error row: Type 'JSON' is not assignable to Record<string, string | ((text: string, reviver?: ...). What is this hack respData = ({} as any) as ResponseData;? This looks like a bug. {} is not a valid ResponseData. What's the type of resp? Please provide a [mcve].

What is JSON and what do you mean with "JSON object"? Do you mean a JavaScript object? JSON is a string format.

This line: <tr *ngFor="let obj of row | keyvalue "> is giving error. Stating row: Type 'JSON' is not assignable to Record<string, string | ((text: string, reviver?: ...)

JSON[] representing array of JSON object to hold list of column entry in (key, value) pair. For details pls refer: Structure of Sample Response section.

What is the interface JSON? Where does it come from? Is it this object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON If it's this object, that's your problem, because the JSON object is not what you think. It's a namespace object that contains static helper functions. It's not a container for data.

It's not representing any user defined interface. JSON is system defined JSON object

Does my last comment solve your problem? If you want to store JSON data, use a string because JSON is a string format. If you want to store the actual data, use an interface for it. I think it's the common case of What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?

No it didn't solve. Problem still persists. And JSON object basically pointing to system defined JSON interface located at "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es5.d.ts"

The JSON object is not a container for JSON data. JSON is a string format. If you want to store JSON, store it in a string. If you want to store the parsed data, it's not JSON and use your own interface. JSON and JavaScript objects are not the same. There are big differences. Don't use the term JSON when you talk about JavaScript objects.

Thanks much @jabaa it solved the issue. When I changed JSON to my custom interface object type.

Solution that worked for me. And it may help others:
export interface CustomJson {
[key: string]: any
}
export interface ResponseData {
action: string,
data: CustomJson[],
warn_info: string
}

It looks like you've learned nothing from this. CustomJson is not JSON. The name is misleading. JSON is not a JavaScript object. JSON is a string format. I don't know where this wrong terminology comes from. I guess it's caused by platforms like Geeksforgeeks that spread wrong terminology. CustomJson { [key: string]: any } is the interface of a common JavaScript object.

Okay, then what is correct way to define it CustomJson. Sorry! for asking as I don't know it @jabaa .

Stop using the term JSON for JavaScript objects. Create an interface that describes the data. Don't use any in your code. Configure your build step to break, when any is used, implicitly or explicitly. interface CustomJson { [key: string]: any } is garbage and shouldn't pass any code review. fetchMetaDatails should work with data of type MetaDetails. Create an interface MetaDetails that describes the structure.

Have defined the interface ResponseData. Is that not right? What is the correct way to define this

ResponseData has a property data. Create an interface for data without any. If different responses have different structures, create multiple interfaces. I don't know the structure. The example data in your questions suggests either interface Data { [key: string]: string } or interface MetaDetailsData { [key: string]: string }. The better you can describe the interface, the more bugs TypeScript can find for you in the build step.

Is this correct? Data Interface: export interface Data { [key: string]: string } And ResponseData interface: export interface ResponseData { action: string, data: Data[], warn_info: string }

If that's your data, yes. In a code review, I would ask why data contains objects and not arrays. It looks like the keys are enumerated. If the actual data isn't enumerated, I would create a specific interface with all possible keys.

Declared as object because it contains data in the form of (key, value) pair. Like: "col1": "val1",...

Yes, but the keys look like an enumeration. Why would you do this? Use an array instead. Why do you need to send the keys? It's redundant.

No its not enumeration. And I do not know what is the correct way to do it. I am new to this Typescript and Angular world. Writing any JS code after many years.
